# React - trying to validate textfield input - "event.target.setValue is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement a text field that only allows numbers from 0 to 99. If the user enters a number that is negative or larger than 99, I want the textfield to reset to 0. Here is my code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";

export default function TestForm() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
 <TextField
            required
            id="field1"
            name="field1"
            label="How Many"
            fullWidth
            type="number"
            defaultValue="0"
            variant="standard"
            onChange={function (event) {
              if (event.target.value < 0 || event.target.value > 99) {
                event.target.setValue("0");
              }
            }}
          />
 </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

When I run this in CodeSandbox I get the following error:

```
event.target.setValue is not a function
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Where did you get info that `.setValue()` is a valid function for HTMLElement?

Comment: u need to set a State ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with a `setValue` property on an input element. But the react way to do it is to hold the value in local state using `useState` and make the `TextField` a controlled element by adding the `value` prop.

```js
export default function TestForm() {
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0)
    return (
        <TextField
            value={value}
            onChange={function (event) {
                if (event.target.value < 0 || event.target.value > 99) {
                    setValue("0");
                } else {
                    setValue(event.target.value)
                }
            }}
        />
    );
}
```

Comment: @vagob64771 You need to import it from the react library, as `React.useState`. Sorry didn't see your import syntax. Let me update my answer

Answer (score 1):

In `react` you need to store the input value in state

Try this code it's help you

```
import React, { useState } from "react"

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState('');

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    if (event.target.value < 0 || event.target.value > 99) {
      setState(event.target.value);
    }
  }
  return (
    <>
      <React.Fragment>
        <TextField
          required
          id="field1"
          name="field1"
          label="How Many"
          fullWidth
          type="number"
          defaultValue="0"
          variant="standard"
          value={state}
          onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    </>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Your initialized value should be a string, not an empty array. Also, you forgot to update the value if the range is valid. Right now you're updating the value if it is not within a valid range and doing nothing if it is valid